# Cannot connect to github but other git repos, bitbucket and ssh do work fine

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys, git-for-windows

When i try to clone a github repository i get

```
Couldn't agree a key exchange algorithm (available: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sh
a2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521)
```

If i try a `git clone` from a private repository, or from my bitbucket account, it works fine.

I am on windows7 64. I use *pageant* as the ssh agent. I've tried both TortoisePlink.exe and plink.exe (this one https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) in the GIT_SSH environment variable.

I've had no problems with this configuration and this ssh keys until i formatted and rebuilt my pc.

I've tried removing and re-adding the keys in my github account, and i've tried with a rsa 1024, rsa 4096 and a ed25519 key.

I'm running the git windows bash. I've also tried with the phpstorm UI, with the same result.

If i try with TortoisePlink.exe this is happening (also, i get a popup window with the above mentioned error):

```
$ git clone git@github.com:foothing/laravel-gdpr-consent.git
Cloning into 'laravel-gdpr-consent'...
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If i try with plink.exe this is happening:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:foothing/laravel-gdpr-consent.git
Cloning into 'laravel-gdpr-consent'...
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa xx:xx:xx
If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
connection.
Store key in cache? (y/n)
```

I hit y and nothing happens (i believe there's something weird happening with the input handling between git and plink)

if i try to connect to github via ssh i get the following

```
$ ssh git@github.com
key_load_public: invalid format
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'x.x.x.x' to the list of known hosts.
Enter passphrase for key '/foo/bar/.ssh/id_rsa':
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi brazorf! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

Git version:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.16.2.windows.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why this question is being downvoted.

This is how i fixed this issue:

- download the latest plink.exe here https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html
- edit GIT_SSH environment variable and make sure it's pointing to plink.exe
- close any shell, terminal, ide, etc.

More details here https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/4105